# Hashing Algorithm - Multiple choices in Solidity

Tags: hash-algorithm

Is it possible to choose another SHA algorithm - say SHA256 - in Solidity?  Anyone having issues with NIST compliance?

Answer (score 2):

SHA256 is built in to Solidity, you use it the same way you call keccak, just

```
sha256(my_data)
```

It is slightly more expensive than keccak, but if you need NIST compliant hashes, SHA256 is the way to go.